# ASP.NET MVC3 @Html.RenderPartial is throwing CS1502 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm building an MVC3 app for my dynamic web class, and while attempting to render a partial, I get the following error:

CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Now, the code I'm executing is this:

```
<div>
    <h2>Shipping Address</h2>
    @Html.RenderPartial("_AddressPartial");
</div>
```

Now, I've googled this, and from what I've seen, the answers are all for older versions of MVC and used the <% %> style syntax and got System.IO errors rather than the System.Web error I'm getting. I did follow their advice though and try with and without the semicolon, which made no difference as I still got the YSOD each time. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the Web.Config been modified in any way?

Comment: Web.Config was only modified for a DB connection string and an API key for my credit card processor, otherwise is the one generated when I created the project

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This might just be because `RenderPartial` doesn't *return* anything. Try either:

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial")
```

or

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_AddressPartial"); }
```

Comment: Using the `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_AddressPartial"); }` version worked! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

Notice that RenderPartial doesn't return any value (just like the RenderAction method), it writes the output on the request. while Partial (just like the Action method) return value of MvcHtmlString.
SO @Html... has to return some value while @{...some code...} doesn't have to.
In your case if you want to use renderPartial use it like that:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_AddressPartial");}
```

But why not use the Partial method, which you can use like that:

```
@Html.Partial("_AddressPartial")
```